# PostgreSQL string_agg with limit

Tags: postgresql

I want to limit string_agg result like:-

```
SELECT string_agg(name, ',') FROM table_a WHERE 'condition' LIMIT 5
```

But the limit part is not working. Is there any other syntax for limiting string_agg results.

Comment: This will limit the result, since aggregate will generate only one row (you don't have any group by clause) there will be nothing to limit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you only want to aggregate 5 rows:

```
SELECT string_agg(name, ',') 
FROM (
  select name 
  from table_a 
  WHERE ... 
  LIMIT 5
) t
```